# Getting keras predictions as a tensor graph for use in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I currently have a custom LSTM model that I have saved as a .h5 file using save(). I am loading this model using load_model() during a tensorflow graph construction, and want to construct a part of the graph using the LSTM model's prediction output (which I therefore need in the form of a tensor). I have established the same session for the tensorflow graph and the keras backend graph, but I am having trouble connecting the output into my tensorflow code graph. Using the standard predict() seems to attempt to run the keras model's session, and I have scoured the internet for something other than hideously converting it to a .pb file and messing with it like that. It seems like it should be easy, considering I am using tensorflow as the Keras backend...Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: https://blog.keras.io/keras-as-a-simplified-interface-to-tensorflow-tutorial.html#using-keras-models-with-tensorflow

Comment: thanks, that was helpful and is pretty much what I ended up doing (the chosen answer demos it some more)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will show how to import saved keras model into tensorflow graph. I will show this using simple single layer feed forward model.

```
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,), name="inputs") 
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="linear", name="outputs")(inputs) 
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs) 
model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="adam")
model.save("model.h5")
```

Now let's load the model using [load_model](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/models/load_model) method of keras and use it in tensorflow to multiply the output of the model with new placeholder tensor.

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model("model.h5")
model_output = model.output
new_tensor_ph = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])
new_output = tf.multiply(model_output, new_tensor_ph)

sess = tf.keras.backend.get_session() 
prediction = sess.run(new_output, feed_dict={model.input:[[3]],new_tensor_ph :[[4]]})
## This works without error
```